# How to include dll,.xml, .txt, .config , pdb and lic files while creating a Nuget package

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, nuspec, nuget-spec

Using **Nuget package explore**r i'm creating nuget packages. There i'm directly adding the lib folder and adding the dll's.

can i add config, XML, lic, pdb directly to the package? or is there any way to add these files while creating package?

And there is one file with extension .AseClient. how can i add this file to the package?

we can **nuspec** for package the assemblies. If i use this process can i add the above mentioned files while creating the package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any one wants to create a nuget package by their own they can go with the Nuget Package explorer it is the easiest way to create packages.

In my case i would like to include dll, xml ,pdb and config files and i would like to create the package with the same folder structure that is existing in my local. You can create a package that supports .Net framework version(4.2,4.5,4.5.1).

1)first click on create package
2)Right hand side on the empty space right click and add Lib to the package
3)Right click on Lib and add .net folder with the version you would like to support either 4.2,4.5,4.5.1 based on requirement.
4) right on the folder which you created and add existing folder add the dll, xml files.
5) if there is any child folders just simple right click on the required folder and add folder.